# Using electron to show value on touch bar slider

Tags: node.js, electron, macbookpro-touch-bar

I would like to show the value from the [`TouchBarSlider`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/touch-bar-slider.md) according to where I move it to. An example example of `TouchBar` can be followed [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/touch-bar.md). I still cannot figure out how to display the value using their given method `change` from `TouchBarSlider`.

My current `main.js` looks like the following.

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, TouchBar} = require('electron')

const {TouchBarLabel, TouchBarSlider} = TouchBar
const slider = new TouchBarSlider({label: 'angle',
                                   minValue: 0,
                                   maxValue: 360})
const result = new TouchBarLabel()
result.label = '30' + ' deg'; 

const updateBar = () => {
  let timeout = 100;
  if (slider.change()){
    result.label = slider.values.toString() + ' deg'
  }
  setTimeout(updateBar, timeout)
}

const touchBar = new TouchBar([
  slider, // add slider
  result // add display for slider value but doesn't work yet
])

let window;

app.once('ready', () => {
  window = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 300,
    height: 200
  });
  window.loadURL('about:blank')
  window.setTouchBar(touchBar);
})

// Quit when all windows are closed and no other one is listening to this.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    app.quit();
});
```

I also have example repository [here](https://github.com/titipata/touchbar-example). You can just replace my given `main.js` in the project in order to try things out. My **electron** version is `1.6.4` and **node** version is `7.4.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, TouchBar } = require('electron');
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

const {TouchBarButton, TouchBarLabel, TouchBarSlider} = TouchBar

const result = new TouchBarLabel();
result.label = '30' + ' deg';

const slider = new TouchBarSlider({
                               label: 'angle',
                               minValue: 0,
                               maxValue: 360,
                               change: (val) => result.label = val.toString() + ' deg' // register event handler here!
                              });

const touchBar = new TouchBar([
  slider, // add slider
  result // add display for slider value
]);

let window;

app.once('ready', () => {
  window = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 300,
  height: 200
 });
  window.loadURL('about:blank');
  window.setTouchBar(touchBar);
});

// Quit when all windows are closed and no other one is listening to this.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  app.quit();
});
```

Working code. Hope this helps! ;)

Comment: This question is not related, but is there a way to send the value from slider to somewhere else like display on `index.html` file?